# Matlab Histogram: connecting bin centers

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

just a simple question but stucked me for a while.

Is there any approaches to connect the center of each bins as curves?

e.g.
[image]

Instead of fitting it with a distribution, is there any simpler way to connect the center of each bin to form a curve?

Comment: But, why? There is a reason distributions are fitted, and not bins linked. The second one won't give you any good information of the data

Comment: Of course there is a way; what have *you* tried to solve this? Please reread [ask]; the most important thing you'll learn there is *show your research*, so in this case: what have you already tried? Given that you know where the bin edges and/or centres are, and that you know the value in each bin, a simple `plot` should suffice.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Hi, thx for the reply, I'm summarizing the result data which is the amount of categories falling into each of the range in X axies and the distribution is not actually making sense. The curve makes it slightly convenient to read.

Comment: @Adriaan Hi, thansk for the answer and I moved to histogram part but cannot find the function to get the coordinates of bin centers directly. BTW, I'm kind of new in Matlab but not novice for stackoverflow.

Comment: If you are not a novice on Stack Overflow, please do not act as one and **show your research**, which every non-novice knows they should.

Comment: Drawing points at the bin centres creates a false illusion of where the counted data points fall. Don't do this if you can avoid it; there's a reason there's not an easy built in method to do so. If you want lines instead of bars, you can use `histogram(..., 'DisplayStyle','stairs')`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are plotting data `y` using `histogram(y)`, you can use the `histogram` object it can return to do what you want;

```
h=histogram(y); hold on;
xvals = (h.BinEdges(2:end)+h.BinEdges(1:end-1))/2;
plot(xvals, h.Values, 'r');
```

The histogram object contains the height values (the bin counts) as well as the bin boundaries. Because there is one more bin boundary than there are bins, and because you would want to plot each point in the centre of the bin, take the average of the two nearest bin edge values (as I did in my calculation of `xvals`).

Answer (score 0):

To end this question, there is my final approach, which is basically the same as @Adriaan's answer.

Instead of working with index and mannual calculation, one can use the convolution method like this:

```
h=histgram(data); hold on;
plot(conv(h.BinEdges, [0.5,0.5],'valid'),h.BinCounts, 'Linewidth',2)
% h.BinCounts provides the data for y axies, while the previous is for x axies.
```

Document for the `conv` function can be found [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html).

Here is the result:
[image]